# How to get Jest to works with v8intrinsic "--allow-natives-syntax"?

Tags: node.js, webpack, jestjs, v8, babel-jest

After @babel/core@^7.6.0, v8intrinsic is supported to be parsed via babel, but run it with node requires a flag --allow-natives-syntax.

We are using node --allow-natives-syntax node_modules/.bin/jest here

When using it inside a jest unit test, jest-runner is not able to recognize % which used to call v8intrinsic.

Like below:

```
describe('foo', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await page.goto(PATH, { waitUntil: 'load' })
  })
  test('should return bar', async () => {
    const foo = await page.evaluate(() => {
      console.log('foo');

      var args = 'testing';
      %GetOptimizationStatus(args);
      
      return foo(args);
    })
    expect(foo).toBe('bar')
  })
})
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you enabling the `"v8intrinsic"` Babel plugin?

See here for details: https://babeljs.io/blog/2019/09/05/7.6.0#v8-intrinsic-runtime-functions-parsing-10148httpsgithubcombabelbabelpull10148

(Note that I wouldn't recommend to rely on V8 intrinsics for anything, not even tests. Especially something like `%GetOptimizationStatus` is an internal detail that can and will change over time. If I were in your (or your team's) place, I wouldn't want to have to debug failing tests just because a new V8 version does some internal stuff slightly differently from before. But of course that's up to you...)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did enable the babel plugin. Somehow it wasn't working. Jest didn't seem to call babel's parser. I am still figuring out where I did wrong.